# Create sublists of scala list

Tags: list, scala, sublist, divide

**Input:** List(1,2,3)

**Expected Output 1:**
List(1), List(1, 2), List(1,2,3)

**Expected Output 2:**
List(1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3)

Comment: What have you done? Why it didn't work?

Comment: i tried with grouping methods. but it is not giving the expected result

Comment: This is one liner that can be done by combining 1-3 build-in methods. Check the docs or inspect what methods your IDE shows to you when you add `.` and press Ctrl/Cmd + Spacebar.

Comment: Isn't "Expected Output 1" just an intermediate step towards "Expected Output 2"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Expected Output 1

```
val l = List(1,2,3)
l.map( x => (l.head to x).toList)
```

Expected Output 2

```
l.flatMap{ x => 
   l.head to x 
}
```

Comment: thank you...got one more method .. val y = List.tabulate(n)(x => 1 to (x+1)).flatten
println(y)